react не отправляет post запрос для авторизации
На сервере DRF api для авторизации отлично работает (использую jwt). Но когда пытаюсь сделать то же самое с реакта, мне пишет Cannot POST /login. На сервере нет информации о post запросе, т.е. проблема именно с фронтендом.
const Login = () => {
    const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    const [error, setError] = useState('');

    const loginUser = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/token/', { username, password });
            localStorage.setItem('access', response.data.access);
            localStorage.setItem('refresh', response.data.refresh);
            setError('');
        } catch (err) {
            setError(err.response.data.message);
        }
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <form class="form_auth_style" method="post">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control item" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Логин" required />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control item" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Пароль" required />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block create-account" type="submit">Вход в аккаунт</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Login;







Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Кто пишет-то? И почему я тут не вижу вызова loginUser?

А как вызвать loginUser? В форме?

По хорошему, форма там вообще не нужна. У вас так же есть 2 неконтролируемых инпута. Добавьте в впорос полный текст ошибки и что при этом видно во вкладке "сеть" браузера? Какой там код вызова? Вот похожий вопрос про отправку формы

Добавила скрин с ошибкой и сетью. На основной вкладке никаких ошибок не выдает, только предупреждение об использовании устаревшей функции. Нигде ничего не пишет, а запросы не отправляются

А ошибка какая? Вы правильно подметили, что ошибка с фронтом. Но там так же ещё и должна быть информация об ошибке

Больше ничего. Нигде. Во всяком случае, я не нашла

Форма прорисовывается, кнопка нажимается, никаких ошибок, кроме той, что я скрин кинула. Он просто не отправляет запросы. Причем только здесь, в авторизации. В другом месте получение данных из базы и добавление новых объектов работает нормально.

У вас по коду нет никаких вызовов кода react, только голая форма с поведение по умолчанию (post переход страницы браузера на эту же открытую страницу). Уберите submit поведение и вызовите вашу функцию авторизации: <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block create-account" onClick={loginUser}>Вход в аккаунт</button>

@AlexKrass
Bad Request: /api/v1/token/
[15/Oct/2024 01:01:03] "POST /api/v1/token/ HTTP/1.1" 400 89
Самая мерзкая из ошибок( А на самой странице пишет все то же, Cannot POST /login

Адрес я проверила, он верный

Если нет никаких переходов, то запрос в инструментах разработчика браузера должен отобразиться на вкладке network/сеть. Можно проанализировать адрес и сами данные, которые ушли. Если у вас есть рабочий пример, то сравнить их между собой на предмет различий (адрес, заголовки, тело запроса). Если это 400, то в основном это уже скорее всего данные, которые были переданы.

@AlexKrass На url сервера, http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/token/, 400 Bad Request. А на url реакта, http://localhost:3000/login, 404. Причем, во вкладке "полезная нагрузка" от фронтенда, логин и пароль указан как надо, а от сервера - пустые строки, {"username":"","password":""}. Это выходит, он с сервером связывается, но данные не передает, сервер выдает 400, а реакт, не получив данные, дает 404, так что ли?

Я скриншоты ошибок добавила

Лучше уберите вообще тег form и замените на div, он по хорошему не должен стучаться на /login. Видимо форма его перебрасывает туда сама по себе браузером.

404 ушла, 400 осталась. Отправляет пустые строки. {
"username": [
"This field may not be blank."
],
"password": [
"This field may not be blank."
]
}

Посмотрите последний абзац для input в ответе, отписал там, а то в комментариях места не много для кода и не очень удобно читается. Если я правильно написал все (не проверил, обычно хук форм используют без чистых данных), то в полезной нагрузке должны увидеть заполненные поля.


Проблемы с запросом на /login

У браузеров есть поведение формы по умолчанию, когда он пытается слать запросы на указанные адреса.
<form action="/api/login" method="get" class="form-example"></form>

Если action не указан, то он посылает данные не текущую страницу, отсюда вы видите лишний запрос по пути /login. Чтобы браузер себя так не вел, обычно это поведение отключают.
<form onSubmit={(e) => e.preventDefault()}>

Ну или просто не использовать тег формы, если данные обрабатываются кодом.

Взаимодействие в React надо явно указывать

У вас сейчас там чистая верстка и код с ним никак не взаимодействует. Если это клик по кнопке, то его надо обрабатывать.
<button 
    class="btn btn-primary btn-block create-account" 
    onClick={loginUser}>
        Вход в аккаунт
</button>

Тоже самое с полями, надо явно указывать, куда положить данные, отсюда данные формы уходят пустые.
<input 
    class="form-control item" 
    type="text" 
    name="username" 
    placeholder="Логин" 
    required 
    value={username} 
    onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)} />

<input 
    class="form-control item" 
    type="password" 
    name="password" 
    placeholder="Пароль" 
    required 
    value={password} 
    onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)} />


Статус 200! Спасибо большое!
